# Zurb Foundation Reveal Modal - preventing close on background click

Tags: javascript, zurb-foundation

When I am opening my [Reveal Modal](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/reveal.html), I would like to prevent it from closing on background click (which is a default behavior).

I am using Zurb Foundation **5.0.2**.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you set the `closeOnBackgroundClick` option to `false` then your `modal` won't close when you click in the background.

```
<div class="reveal-modal" data-options="closeOnBackgroundClick:false">
```

Comment: This doesn't work in the most recent version of Foundation, the option is no longer camel cased so you need to use `data-options="close_on_background_click:false"`

Comment: For Foundation 6 you need to camelCase the properties, so it looks like this `data-options="closeOnClick:false;closeOnEsc:false;"`

Comment: @iopener .. Out of curiosity .. where did you find that info? I looked in their docs http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/reveal.html and I can't see any reference to it. Thanks!

Comment: @SorinTrimbitas Yeah, they haven't filled out the docs yet, but after some searching a comment at the end of this page http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33855505/zurb-foundation-6-reveal-doesnt-work mentioned that these options *don't* work when using the .foundation('open') technique, so I tried them without that technique and they worked fine.

Comment: For foundation 6 see this: http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/36653#comment_27593

Answer (score 15):

Yehhhhh Finally Found It:

Put below code on your foundation reveal model. Than it not close by clicking on background or by pressing esc key.

data-options="close_on_background_click:false;close_on_esc:false;"

Ex:

```
<div id="AccessContainer" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal data-options="close_on_background_click:false;close_on_esc:false;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 8):

For anyone looking at this question in 2018, I'm using Version 6.4.0 and this works:

```
data-close-on-click="false" data-close-on-esc="false"
```

I added that to the reveal div like this and it's working (as of July 2018):

```
<div class="reveal" id="modalVideo" data-reveal data-close-on-click="false" data-close-on-esc="false">
```

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this globally by executing the following line of JavaScript before showing any modals:

```
Foundation.libs.reveal.settings.close_on_background_click = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

For latest version of foundation by zurb use following snippet

```
<div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal"  data-options="close_on_background_click:false" data-reveal>
```

Complete Code will look like

```html
<a href="#" data-reveal-id="myModal" id="dd">Click Me For A Modal</a>
<div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal"  data-options="close_on_background_click:false" data-reveal>
    <h2>Awesome. I have it.</h2>
<p class="lead">Your couch.  It is mine.</p>
<p>I'm a cool paragraph that lives inside of an even cooler modal. Wins!</p>
<a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
</div>
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me.  This is my html:
<div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal" data-options="close_on_background_click:false" data-reveal aria-labelledby="modalTitle" aria-hidden="true" role="dialog" >

Answer (score 1):

If using the stand-alone Reveal plugin here: https://zurb.com/playground/reveal-modal-plugin

Use the following on the link that opens the modal.

```
<a href="#" data-reveal-id="myModal" data-closeonbackgroundclick="false">Open Modal</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer applies to `Foundation 6`. Below are the correct option for both preventing close on background click (`closeOnClick:false;`) and preventing close via the `Esc` key (`closeOnEsc:false;`).

```
<div class="reveal" id="exampleModal1" data-reveal
    data-options="closeOnClick:false; closeOnEsc:false;">
```