# Foundation modal closeOnClick closeOnEsc not working

Tags: modal-dialog, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

I'm using vue and foundation 6.2.3 to create a modal:

```
<div :id="modalId" class="reveal" data-reveal v-foundation-element aria-labelledby="modal button" aria-hidden="true"
     role="dialog" :data-options="allowEscape ? 'closeOnClick:true;closeOnEsc:true;' : 'closeOnClick:false;closeOnEsc:false;'">
```

When I click the button the modal shows up, but I can click outside the modal body and press escape to close the modal despite `closeOnClick:false` and `closeOnEsc:false` being set.

Here's the twist: I'm using hot reload with webpack and I can do a weird thing to make it start working.

1. I remove `v-foundation-element` from the div
2. I save and reload the page.
3. I add `v-foundation-element` back to the div
4. the page gets hot reloaded
5. I can no longer click/esc out of the modal

here's the rendered HTML for the modal when it's in the working state:

```
<div id="choose-your-package" data-reveal="ianmsm-reveal" aria-labelledby="Choose Your Package" aria-hidden="false" role="dialog" data-options="closeOnClick:false;closeOnEsc:false;" class="reveal" data-yeti-box="choose-your-package" data-resize="choose-your-package" tabindex="-1" style="display: block; top: 129px;">
```

and here's the modal in the non-working state:

```
<div id="choose-your-package" data-reveal="axb8cp-reveal" aria-labelledby="Choose Your Package" aria-hidden="false" role="dialog" data-options="closeOnClick:false;closeOnEsc:false;" class="reveal" data-yeti-box="choose-your-package" data-resize="choose-your-package" data-events="resize" style="top: 129px; display: block;" tabindex="-1">
```

I'm not sure why this is happening.  How do I make it work consistently?

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you are trying to use the JSON options in the data attribute, which, as far as I know isn’t possible.

Try setting `data-close-on-esc="false"` and `data-close-on-click= "false"`. Maybe the plugin you have has the JS options allowed in data options, but I doubt it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21922511/zurb-foundation-reveal-modal-preventing-close-on-background-click

This link shows that those settings should work fine in foundation 6